# Executing VideoReader('movie.mp4') takes so long in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video, process

I am trying to read many video files from a database and process them. I am using Matlab and my problem is that when I want to read a 10 minutes long full HD video I should wait so much and my computer stops performing well. I use this command

```
VideoReader('movie.mp4')
```

I have seen that it takes 47 seconds to read a 30 seconds long video in the same format. I do not need to load all frames into my memory I just need 11 frames for each step of my process and really got stock here. Any help will be appreciated. 
Also here is my output when I run this command

```
disp(videoObj);
```

output:

```
Summary of Multimedia Reader Object for 'movie.mp4'.

Video Parameters:  30.00 frames per second, RGB24 1280x720.
                 1482 total video frames available.
```

By the way I am running my code on Matlab R2014a and my OS is ubuntu 14.0.4.

Comment: What is the file size of the video? What is the output of the resultant object once the video does load? What does `mmfileinfo` return (be sure to expand the Audio and Video structs)? What OS and `version` of Matlab? Does the issue persist after relaunching Matlab?

Comment: Hi, the file size is 1.5 GB. The output is a VideoReader object and I have used it and implemented my method for short-length videos. My OS is ubuntu 14 and my Matlab version is R2014a. Finally, yes the issue does persist even after relanching Matlab.

Comment: Yes, of course the output is a VideoReader object – what are the values of its properties, i.e., what is `disp(vidObj)`? I'd like to see all of the codec info, etc. Edit your question. Because you're on Linux, I'm guessing this may be due to the video codecs you have installed. Make sure you have the [latest versions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-video-file-formats.html).

Comment: I have done as you said. I will check the link and see if I have installed the latest versions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Siavash,
The long loading time is because the entire file is scanned to determine the number of frames. This process is necessary to support frame indexed based access. In R2014b and higher, the frame counting during construction has been disabled. Additionally, you can seek to specific locations in the file using the CurrentTime property and use the hasFrame/readFrame methods for reading to avoid this performance penalty

Dinesh

Answer (score -1):

I'm using version R2015b and I find the same slow processing of mp4 files with the VideoReader and readFrame functions.  However, I find that those functions perform much faster on an avi file than an mp4, so I first convert the mp4 to avi  using an independent program from https://www.ffmpeg.org.  I don't know why there's such a difference in speed between the two...perhaps someone from MATLAB can provide some insight into that question.